# How GDB startup files work?

Tags: gdb

How do I save my current GDB session? and How do I load it again on GDB startup later. There is a brief discussion on .*gdbinit* in [Art of debugging](http://www.amazon.in/The-Art-Debugging-GDB-Eclipse/dp/1593271743) , Chapter 1. But I really don't get the saving part. Is it an autosave?

Comment: The .gdbinit is usually used to save some configurations, so after restarting gdb, it can read the related configurations from the file. What is the exact meaning of GDB session?

Comment: "The .gdbinit is usually used to save some configurations" -- Can you describe me how? Also by GDB session I mean suppose you were debugging some code, mean time you had to quit GDB. But when you comeback you want to start from exactly where you left it. How to save and load the configuration, this is perhaps to the point.

Answer (score 2):

The .gdbinit file saves some configurations and user-defined commands. When gdb starts, it will try to search .gdbinit file according to some sequences (For the sequences, you can refer https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options). For .gdbinit file, you can refer this as an example:https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit/blob/master/gdbinit.

I think you want to store the whole memory dump into the file, then restart gdb, it will reload it. I have search the invoking gdb manual(https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Invoking-GDB.html#Invoking-GDB), but can't find gdb can do it.

Personally, I think this file you request is very similar to core dump file.